# Filtering on subqueries using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dynamic

I'm working on a large application which is using [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)  for filtering .

All of the classes in my data-access-layer are derived from a common ancestor DALAncestor which, among other things, defines method GetData: public abstract List GetData(Filter filter)

An implementation of this method for a Customer would look like this (simplified):

```
public override List<Entities.Customer> GetData(Filter filter) {
  var customers = from c in db.Customers
                  select new Entites.Customer { 
                    ID = c.ID,
                    FullName = c.Name,
                    Country = c.Country
                  };

   return = filter.Apply(customers).ToList();
}
```

"Apply" is a method which takes a collection of conditions and applies all of them using Dynamic LINQ Libary.

Method GetData is called like this:

```
private void DemoCallGetDataMethod() {
  var filter = new Filter();
  filter.AddCondition("Country", "Austria");

  var list = myCustomerDAL.GetData(filter);
  // do something
}
```

SQL Server gets a select statment:

```
SELECT [t0].ID, [t0].Name, [t0].Country
  FROM Customer [t0]
 WHERE [t0].Country = @p0
```

(@p0 is a parameter with its value set to "Austria").

Everything works great, if I want to filter values only on the "top" (master) level. However, since I build my filter on user's input on the filter form, there are cases in which users want to filter by a value in detail level (i.e. columns to be filtered by are known only after a user clicks "Search").

I cannot find a solution for this: "Get all of the customers from Austria, who bought Pepsi".

I've tried several things, none of them seems to be working. The basic idea is:

1. [Add support for CONTAINS](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html) to DynamicLibrary
2. Change my code to

```
public override List<Entities.Customer> GetData(Filter filter) {
  var customers = from c in db.Customers
                  select new Entites.Customer { 
                    ID = c.ID,
                    FullName = c.Name,
                    Country = c.Country,
                    Items = c.Order.SelectMany(o => o.Item).Select(i => i.ItemId).ToList()
                  };

  return = filter.Apply(customers).ToList();
}

private void DemoCallGetDataMethod() {
  var filter = new Filter();
  filter.AddCondition("Country","=", "Austria");
  filter.AddCondition("Items","Contains", "11"); // 11 = Id for Pepsi

  var list = myCustomerDAL.GetData(filter);

  // do something
}
```

The exepction thrown is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'Contains' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or am I just going in wrong direction and I should try a some other approach? Which? :)

EDITED: changed my example

Comment: Sorry Iam not sure what you are after, the article you mentioned has also provided an answer to the same problem you are facing to avoid that exception. And because you want to follow that route, I really dont understand what you are after :)?

Comment: filter.AddCondition("Items","Contains", "Pepsi");  -- This only works for String and String, not List<string> and string

Comment: @user182630 I want to be able to filter by values from subselects in general, not only for a specific case. The approach from that article works only if you hard code you filters, which is not a thing I can do.

Comment: @Tsabo No, it works on lists, too (I tested it). But you're right: maybe I should give an example with ints instead of strings

Answer (score 2):

> @user182630 I want to be able to filter by values from subselects in
>   general, not only for a specific case. The approach from that article
>   works only if you hard code you filters, which is not a thing I can
>   do. – Marko Juvančič 9 mins ago

Have a read through this article http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I use PredicateBuilder for dynamic queries in my applications.

[Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

In your case I imagine it will be something like:

```
 string MyCountry = "Austria";
 string MyProductId = 11

 var Predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<db.Customers>();
 Predicate = Predicate.And(p=>p.Country ==MyCountry && p.Order.SelectMany(o=>o.Item).Where(i=>i.id == 11).Count() >0);

 var list = Customers.Where(Predicate).Select(s=>s).ToList();
```

Comment: This approach fails on "columns to be filtered by are known only after a user clicks Search" requirement.

Comment: Well if all the columns are known in advance then this is not a problem.

Comment: They're not. Method "Apply" filter doesn't know anything about the columns.

Comment: But there are some interface members that must know something about the columns, so that you can select your filter.